# Can't start: error in configuration file(s) Can't find setting 'Scenario.nrofHostGroups' Java Result: -1

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, ios-simulator, simulator

I am working on one simulator with netbeans IDE. I downloaded one simulator from their official website and it's install an running correctly in cmd.
[image]

I import existing project of one simulator into netbeans IDE and included all three libraries, so it have no error. But when i click on run icon, it gives me the following error.
[image]

So, as you see on the console tab(text with red marker), that's the error in which i need help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you working directory in not correctly set in Eclipse for this project.

I was having same problem so I changed it.

Here is screenshot of my working directory. This Might help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

During the configuration of One with eclipse make sure that your run configuration path must be in synchronization with the arguments otherwise it will throws an error like you posted.

**Steps:**

1. Go to Run -> Run Configurations
2. After setting the proper configuration of one eclipse, Click on *DTNSim* present in core
3. Open Run Configuration Window
4. Click on Java Application-> Open Drag bar-> Click on DTNSim
5. Go To Arguments
6. Check Default and Others path:

It must be like the picture attached here!

One Simulator Working Window

[image]